# Pass Attributes (not functions) to python `pandas.DataFrame.style`

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-styles

I have a `pandas.DataFrame` with values in it, say:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 3), columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

In [160]: df
Out[160]:
          a         b         c
0 -0.316527 -0.721590  1.812285
1 -1.704653 -0.415888 -0.294740
2 -1.126637  0.032084 -1.344484
3  0.081789 -1.311954  1.941496
4  0.617405  0.114212 -0.763610
```

Now **I've written my own color gradient functions** so that I get a `pd.DataFrame` of the same size and shape, but with color hex codes for each cell, say:

```
df_clrs = pd.DataFrame([
    ['#bc4700', '#dea380', '#bc4700'], 
    ['#384f69', '#dea380', '#bc4700'], 
    ['#dea380', '#bc4700', '#384f69'], 
    ['#384f69', '#384f69', '#dea380'],
    ['#dea380', '#bc4700', '#384f69']], 
    columns=['a', 'b', 'c']
)

In [164]: df_clrs
Out[164]:
         a        b        c
0  #bc4700  #dea380  #bc4700
1  #384f69  #dea380  #bc4700
2  #dea380  #bc4700  #384f69
3  #384f69  #384f69  #dea380
4  #dea380  #bc4700  #384f69
```

I let's say I've done this as well with text colors, so:

```
 df_fnts = pd.DataFrame([
    ['#f1f1f1','#f1f1f1','#000000'],
    ['#000000','#f1f1f1','#f1f1f1'],
    ['#000000','#f1f1f1','#000000'],
    ['#f1f1f1','#000000','#f1f1f1'],
    ['#000000','#000000','#f1f1f1']],
    columns=['a', 'b' ,'c']
)

In [167]: df_fnts
Out[167]:
         a        b        c
0  #f1f1f1  #f1f1f1  #000000
1  #000000  #f1f1f1  #f1f1f1
2  #000000  #f1f1f1  #000000
3  #f1f1f1  #000000  #f1f1f1
4  #000000  #000000  #f1f1f1
```

My goal is to now expose the `DatFrame.style` functionality, as demonstrated in [these tutorials](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html).

However, all of the functions demonstrated in tutorial focus on passing a function (using the `pd.DataFrame.style.applymap`), however, I have all of the properties already created.

#### Things I've Tried

Because in the documentation it looks like you need to append the value with the appropriate property, I've created a function like this:

```
def _apply_prop(df, prop):
   return df.applymap(lambda x: prop + ':' + x)

# apply the color mapping
df.style.applymap(
    _apply_prop(
        df_clrs, 
       'background-color'
    )
).to_excel('~/Desktop/background-colors.xlsx')
```

But I get a `TypeError`

```
TypeError: the first argument must be callable
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`df` (5x3) and `df_clrs` (4x3) have different shapes. Assuming you got that corrected, try this:

```
def _apply_prop(_, style, prop):
    return style.applymap(lambda x: prop + ':' + x)

df.style.apply(_apply_prop, axis=None, style=df_clrs, prop='background-color')
```

Output:

[image: Styled data frame]

Some notes:

- Don't call `style.applymap`. It iterates over *cells*. Use [`apply(..., axis=...)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply.html) to iterate over column / row / table. Whatever you iterate over, return an object with the same shape.
- You do not execute the styling function in `apply / applymap`. You supply the function's name along with its parameters
- The first parameter of the styling function is always the data frame being styled. `apply / applymap` implicitly passes the data frame to the styling function. You can pass additional arguments by keywords.

Comment: I've changed the question so the matrices are the same, thanks for the catch! Your solution was great -- I ended up figuring out a version that I will detail below in a separate answer, but I accepted your answer as the correct answer to the question (I'll just add mine below for completeness).

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't exactly what you are wanting, but it does succesfully apply the colors to the df_clrs DataFrame

```py
def apply_prop(val):
    return 'color: %s' % val
df_clrs.style.applymap(apply_prop)
```

the applymap is only able to except a function as an object. So you aren't going to be able to add arguments to the function.

Keep in mind that the idea of the styling is to style based on the data in the dataframe that is being styled.  Not another DataFrame.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up coming up with a different solution that:

1. Avoids using `applymap` (as I recall applying to all elements is a slower operation)
2. Leverages the "column name" in an `apply` function to reference the appropriate column of the styling matrix.

```py
def _apply_format(srs, df, prop):
    """
    Parameters
    ----------
    srs : :class:`Series`
        This is the column that will be passed automatically in the `apply` function
    df : :class:`DataFrame`
        The matrix of styling attributes with the same shape as the matrix to be styled
    prop : str
        The property to style, e.g. 'background-color'
    """
    nm  = srs.name
    row = df[nm]
    return (prop + ': ' + row).tolist()
```

Now I can just chain together the styling functionality for background colors and font colors, like so:

```py
(df.style.
         apply(_apply_format, axis=0, subset=subset, **{'df': df_clrs, 'prop': 'background-color'}).
         apply(_apply_format, axis=0, subset=subset, **{'df': df_fnts, 'prop': 'color'}).
         to_excel('~/Desktop/pretty-table.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
     )
```

[image]